# are GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture2D coordinates normalized or no?

Tags: texture2d, glsles

I understand that most textures are normalized except GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE.

However, I can't find information on GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES. Are the coordinates normalized or in the range of [0, imageWidth], [0, imageHeight]?

I would also appreciate if you mention where you got the information from. I couldn't find it on khronos website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use normalized texture coordinates. You can address them with texture coordinates in the range [0.0, 1.0]. While it might have been nice to point that out in the extension spec, they probably thought it was not necessary because it's just like all other textures in OpenGL ES.

Source: Tried it on a Kindle Fire HDX 7" tablet.

Comment: I also tried it on Android and seems to work with [0.0, 1.0]. Negative indices magically don't create exceptions inside Texture2D function.

Answer (score 1):

Like you I frustratingly couldn't quickly find a definitive statement. However...

The extension documentation for [OES_EGL_image_external](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt) mentions both that:

> Their default min filter is `LINEAR`.  It is an `INVALID_ENUM` error to set the min filter value to anything other than `LINEAR` or `NEAREST`.

And:

> The default s and t wrap modes are `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` and it is an
>   `INVALID_ENUM` error to set the wrap mode to any other value.

Which are pretty clear clues that coordinates aren't normalised if you're used to dealing with non-power-of-two textures. Indeed the whole tenor of the extension — that one to three hardware sampling units may be used, that some varyings may be lost and that only a single level-of-detail is permitted — strongly reserves the right for an implementation to do the exact same thing as if you'd sampled Y, U and V separately from non-power-of-two sources and combined them arithmetically yourself.

But in terms of providing a thorough finger-on-paper answer:  `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` is defined [by the appropriate man page](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml) as:

> `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` causes coordinates to be clamped to the range `(1/2N, 1 - 1/2N)`, where  `N` is the size of the texture in the direction of
>   clamping.

... which, again, makes little sense if coordinates were normalised (though it wouldn't actually be undefined).

So I'm willing to gamble strongly that they're not normalised.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I have to read between the lines here. I'll keep experimenting with this and post an update whenever I have a proof.